# Sending mail from /etc/profile file

Tags: command-line, email

I added an email command to the `/etc/profile` file like this:

```
echo test | mail -s "test mail" me@my.domain &
```

The `&` at the end of the line is for running the mail command in background to not add a delay to the login prompt.

Everything works well, but if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I can see the result of the mail command at the prompt:

```
[1]+  Done       echo test | mail -s "test mail" me@my.domain
```

If I remove the `&` at the end of the line the problem doesn't appear but I don't have the command in the background.

Comment: I also added  >/dev/null 2>&1 & to do a test but nothing changed.

Comment: Look at the `disown` [built-in shell command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins).

Answer (score 3):

Try putting it in a sub shell:

```
`echo test | mail -s "test mail" me@my.domain &`
```

it should do the job.

Also redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr` at the same time works for me:

```
echo test | mail -s "test mail" me@my.domain &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: Backquotes necessary?

Comment: Yeah, we are using them to run the command in a sub shell. just like `$( ... )`.

Comment: The first solution worked but the sub shell is executed not in background (I see the wait before the prompt. The second solution didn't worked (I see the result of the mail command)

Comment: Ok the second solution worked but using backquotes. Thank you!

Comment: @MicheleFiore you are welcome, you can accept the answer if you like, so other will know that it works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an `!` in addition to the `&` this way your command is not only executed in the background but also disowned by your current shell:

```
echo test | mail -s "test mail" me@my.domain &!
```

This works for me using zsh.

Comment: Works in `bash` too ;)